# path.js:1086 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I was following the Webpack guide and get stuck [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-source-maps) while running `npm run build` I received the this error:

```
path.js:1086
          cwd = process.cwd();
                        ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1086:25)
    at Function.Module._resolveLookupPaths (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:479:17)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:587:20)
```

I checked all imports and everything is looking fine. Than I thought is should caching issue so I ran `npm cache clean -f` surprisingly I get the exact same error. Probably it is **NodeJS** problem but I have no idea how to debug it.

Here is my file structure:

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test_webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    print: './src/print.js',
    sec: './src/secondClick.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      titile: "Output manager from webpack n12"
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Answer (score 228):

Closing all terminal windows and opening it again worked for me.

[Reference](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/249#issuecomment-327794156)

Comment: You could probably be running a `git clone` on the same directory in another terminal window like I was did.

Comment: This often means that node is trying to read a directory with a stale file handle (i.e. it's been replaced or deleted and you don't know it yet), which is why turning it off and turning it on again helps.

Answer (score 56):

It seems that your shell just went crazy :),
Just `cd.. && cd [the folder you tried running the command]` and everything will get back to normal.

Comment: The directory you are in has been deleted (another may have been created with the same name).  

Think of it as dying and waking up your reincarnated body, thinking you are still in your old body.  You have to go up before you come back down to your new reality.

Comment: I have to do this with every other yarn command. Which seems a bit absurd. The directory isn't deleted at all, that'd be awjward for an entire repo to be deleted every time `yarn` is ran.

Comment: This also happens if you are in a removable drive and it disconnects, A bluetooth drive would be nice 

Comment: My problem was this: I have removed the directory I was currently working in. Then copied a newer folder back with the same name. To me everything was back to normal, but the terminal had other ideas. This solution fixed the corrupted state of the terminal and the `npm install` command ran successfully.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me from running node in a folder that I had just removed. Just move to a folder that exists.

```
cd
```

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the PC might help as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change in your `webpack.config`:

```
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    print: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/print.js'),
    sec: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/secondClick.js')
  },
```

And make sure you run the command from the project root with:
`npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the terminal is pointing to a folder that I replaced with another (same name, different contents). After restarting or doing cd.. and back we can get npm working properly.

Comment: the same thing happened to me

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that you have renamed a folder and your shell got messed up.

Reference:

https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/249#issuecomment-163884583

Answer (score -1):

I would say the error is pretty clear.

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

So this is interpreted as **'The directory is incorrect or I can't find the directory you are pointing to right now.'**

In my case;
I was inside the /test folder and I was supposed to switch to the main project folder and then indicate which file to run.

```
node specs/tests/config.js
```

The error I was receiving through chdir('...') method and this was not located inside /test folder, but it was under the /project folder.

Comment: The error is obvious sure, but it's wrong when the dir actually does exist. And you can open a new shell and see that.